# Why doesn't a custom resourceGenerator get executed upon compile?

Tags: sbt

I'm following the SBT docs on [How to generate resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources) trying to get a resourceGenerator task in a plugin to run on compile.

It's as simple as you see in the docs:

```
object TestResourcePlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  import SbtWeb.autoImport._
  import WebKeys._

  override def requires = SbtWeb && plugins.JvmPlugin

  override def trigger  = AllRequirements

  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
      val file = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "test"
      val contents = "test file"
      IO.write(file, contents)
      Seq(file)
    }.taskValue
  )
}
```

I've encountered a situation where the `sbt.plugin.JvmPlugin` was resetting the `sourceGenerators in Compile` key, meaning my adding a task to it wouldn't do anything unless I had required the `JvmPlugin` to be loaded first (as I am doing above). Is there something similar happening here?

Comment: What does your build look like?

i.e. Project(..., settings = Default.defaultSettings) is deprecated as it overrides ALL autoplugin settings.

Comment: I have an sbt-scripted test here that has the build file set up: https://github.com/michaeldfallen/sbt-mustache/blob/master/plugin/src/sbt-test/mustache/compile/build.sbt

Comment: The actual resource task has moved on since I posted this but the latest code can be seen here: https://github.com/michaeldfallen/sbt-mustache/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/io/michaelallen/mustache/sbt/SbtMustache.scala#L36

Comment: Upon further investigation I think resourceGenerators aren't actually meant to be executed on compile, only on the run task. Might be I got this wrong and it's working as it should.

Comment: Package will also force em to run.

Comment: That's not obvious, but makes sense to have `resourceGenerators` executed only when the resources are really needed, i.e. upon `run` or `package` executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything added to the Resource Generators key will only be executed when it is actually needed, on the run task for example.

This was user error and a misunderstanding of the SBT docs only.