# managed resource available only for freshly cleaned project

Tags: sbt

I created a SBT AutoPlugin that generates resources:
https://github.com/sphereio/json-schema-inliner/

(Thx to [Why doesn't a custom resourceGenerator get executed upon compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125063/why-doesnt-a-custom-resourcegenerator-get-executed-upon-compile/25180394#25180394), I could fix my first problem.)

There is a test project that generates "test/inline/category.schema.json" for example.

The test project is in GIT as well: https://github.com/sphereio/json-schema-inliner/tree/master/testProject

This generated resource is available with a freshly cleaned project:

```
cd testProject

▶ sbt clean run
[...]
[info] Running Main
url from test/category.schema.json: file:/Users/yannsimon/projects/json-schema/testProject/target/scala-2.10/classes/test/category.schema.json
url from test/inline/category.schema.json: file:/Users/yannsimon/projects/json-schema/testProject/target/scala-2.10/classes/test/inline/category.schema.json
```

When running again, the managed resource disappears from "testProject/target/scala-2.10/classes/test/inline"

```
▶ sbt run
[...]
[info] Running Main
url from test/category.schema.json: file:/Users/yannsimon/projects/json-schema/testProject/target/scala-2.10/classes/test/category.schema.json
url from test/inline/category.schema.json: null
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Yann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in sbt issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2168#issuecomment-144133794

The fix was this is very simple: https://github.com/sphereio/json-schema-inliner/commit/eeb490189781e93c8c6eb15b504a158ce425b653